# Water to prevent dehydration before kiddush on Shabbos morning?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, water, kiddush

The halocho is that after davenning on Shabbos morning, it is forbidden to drink water until one has made kiddush. See [dinonline](https://dinonline.org/2014/12/19/water-before-kiddush/).

Consider the following situation: one has davenned on a warm Shabbos morning and now intends to learn for an hour before eating.

Is there any source that permits drinking water purely to prevent dehydration until kiddush?

Comment: Is the person a Choleh?

Comment: How about the person learns after making Kiddush?

Comment: @DoubleAA The person is healthy but feels that he will get dehydrated if he does not drink.

Comment: @ClintEastwood Imagine a case where there are no ingredients with which to make kiddush without a significant interruption.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, if there's a risk to one's health, one's health takes precedence over these (and most other) Halachot, especially since these are D'Rabanan (Rabbinical).

If there's merely discomfort:

The Rambam in הלכות שבת - פרק תשעה ועשרים allows one to drink water before Kiddush.

> **ה** אָסוּר לְאָדָם לֶאֱכל אוֹ  לִשְׁתּוֹת יַיִן מִשֶּׁקָּדַשׁ הַיּוֹם עַד שֶׁיְּקַדֵּשׁ. וְכֵן מִשֶּׁיָּצָא הַיּוֹם אָסוּר לוֹ לְהַתְחִיל לֶאֱכל וְלִשְׁתּוֹת וְלַעֲשׂוֹת מְלָאכָה אוֹ לִטְעֹם כְּלוּם עַד שֶׁיַּבְדִּיל. **וְלִשְׁתּוֹת מַיִם מֻתָּר**.‏

However, the Shulchan Aruch in סימן רעא - דיני קדוש על היין forbids one from drinking before Kiddush, and that's how we Pasken; that's the generally accepted custom.

> **ד** אָסוּר  לִטְעֹם כְּלוּם קֹדֶם שֶׁיְּקַדֵּשׁ, אֲפִלּוּ מַיִם.‏

And again for the morning Kiddush in סימן רפט - סדר סעדת שחרית של שבת he says:

> וְשֶׁלֹּא יִטְעֹם קֹדֶם לוֹ כְּלוּם כְּמוֹ בְּקִדּוּשׁ הַלַּיְלָה‏

However, the Be'er Heitev, referring to the evening Kiddush,  does allow one to rinse out one's mouth, *since one has no intention of enjoying the taste.*

> באר היטב  (**ד**) **לטעום**. נ''ל דשרי לרחוץ פיו כיון דאינו מכוון להנאת טעימה.‏

So, if nothing else, one could rinse out one's mouth to prevent dehydration.

**In theory**, an argument could be made that sipping a minute amount of water to prevent the discomfort of dehydration - as opposed to enjoying the *taste* of the water - would be similar. However, **in practice**, one would need a competent Rabbinic Authority to decide that. CYLOR.

---

More source material from [WikiSource](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%97%D7%91%D7%9C_%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%AA%D7%95_%D7%98_%D7%99)

**א. אכילה ושתיה קודם קידוש**‏

פסק **הרמב"ם** (הל' שבת פכ"ט ה"ה): "אסור לאדם לאכול או לשתות יין משקדש היום עד שיקדש. ולשתות המים מותר, שכח או עבר ואכל ושתה קודם שיקדש או קודם שיבדיל הרי זה מקדש ומבדיל אחר שאכל".‏

ובאר **המגיד משנה**:‏
"אסור לאדם לאכול או לשתות יין משקדש היום וכו'. כך היא הנסחא בקצת הספרים ויראה מזה שלשתות מים מותר קודם קידוש כמו קודם הבדלה. ויש שכתוב בהן או לשתות סתם. ואף לזאת הנסחא אפשר שדעת רבינו ממ"ש בסיום הבבא ולשתות מים מותר שאף קודם קידוש מותר. ובגמ' (דף ק"ה) גבי הבדלה מפורש רבנן דבי רב אשי לא קפדי אמיא, ויש לדמות קידוש להבדלה כדברי רבינו. **והרשב"א** ז"ל השיב שקודם קידוש אפי' לשתות מים אסור והביא ראיה מן הירושלמי וכן נהגו".‏

ו**בהגהות מיימוניות** (אות ה) כתב: "צ"ע דלא מצאנו היתר אפילו למים והא דרבנן דבי רב אשי לא קפדי אמיא משמע בספר דלא קאי אקודם קידוש אלא אקודם הבדלה ע"ש דמייתי לה אדרב הונא ותנא משמיה דר' יעקב דאמר הטועם קודם שיבדיל מיתתו באסכרא כו' ע"ש. וכן מהר"ם אומר שאסור לטעום אפילו מים קודם קידוש וכן בשחרית קודם קדושא רבה ע"כ".‏

וכן **בשו"ת הרא"ש** (כלל כה סי' ב) פסק שאסור בשתית מים קודם קידוש.‏

וכ"כ ב**טור** (או"ח סי' רעא) "ואסור לטעום כלום בין מים ובין יין משתחשך עד שיקדש".‏

וה**בית יוסף** באר שם: "ואסור לטעום כלום וכו'. בפרק ערבי פסחים (קו:) איכא מאן דאמר טעם אינו מקדש, ואע"ג דאסיקנא טעם מקדש מכל מקום משמע דלכתחלה אסור לטעום מדלא אמרינן טועם ואחר כך מקדש, ואמרינן נמי התם (קה.) דשבת קבעה נפשה כלומר קובעת לקידוש שאסור לטעום עד שיקדש, וגם כן מתבאר מדין שאחר זה, וכן כתב הרמב"ם בפרק כ"ט (ה"ה). וכתב שם הרב המגיד שנראה מדבריו שמותר לשתות מים קודם קידוש כמו קודם הבדלה אבל הרשב"א (שו"ת ח"ג סי' רסד) אוסר והביא ראיה מהירושלמי (פסחים ריש פ"י) וכן נהגו ע"כ. וכן כתבו שם הגהות (מיימוניות אות ה) בשם הר"מ, וזה דעת רבינו (=הטור) שאסר לשתות אפילו מים, וגם דברי הרמב"ם אפשר לפרש שמה שכתב לשתות מים מותר לא קאי אקידוש אלא אהבדלה לחודה". וא"כ עולה מדבריו שאף בשתיית מים יש להחמיר לפני הקידוש.‏

וכך פסק ב**שו"ע** (או"ח סי' רעא ס"ד): "אסור לטעום כלום קודם שיקדש, אפי' מים. ". וכן כתב הגר"א שאף מים אסור קודם קידוש.‏

והעיר ה**מגן אברהם** (ס"ק ה): "אסור לטעום – נ"ל דשרי לרחוץ פיו, כיון דאינו מכוין להנאת טעימה וכ"מ בת"ה סי' קנ"ח ועסי' תקס"ז ותרי"ב ומשחשיכה אפילו לא קבל שבת ואם קיבל שבת אפילו מבע"י אסור לטעום (ב"ח) ונ"ל דאם רוצה לקבל שבת מבע"י ולקדש ולאכול ולהתפלל ערבית בלילה רשאי וכמ"ש סי' רס"ז ועמ"ש רסי' ער"ב".‏

וכן ב**משנה ברורה** (ס"ק יא) הוסיף: "אסור לטעום – וזהו רק איסור דרבנן והטעם כיון דחיוב של הקידוש חל עליו מיד בכניסת שבת ואפילו לא קבל עליו שבת בהדיא, דכיון שנעשה ספק חשיכה ממילא חל עליו שבת ואם קבל עליו שבת אפילו עדיין יום גדול דינא הכי. ואם רוצה לקבל שבת מבע"י ולקדש ולאכול ולהתפלל ערבית אח"כ בלילה רשאי ובתנאי שיהיה חצי שעה קודם זמן מעריב כדלעיל בסימן רל"ה ס"ב [א"ר]". וכוונתו שאם הגיע זמן חצי שעה לפי תפילת ערבית אסור לאכול לפני קיום המצוה.‏

Comment: I'm no medical expert — far from it — but don't think rinsing one's mouth without swallowing will help prevent dehydration.

Comment: @msh210 - he's obviously not dehydrated in the medical sense (otherwise he could even be Mechalel Shabbat to treat it), but he feels like he desperately needs a drink.